# "no transactions/positions to chart" Error in my code using quantstrat

Tags: r, trading, algorithmic-trading, quantstrat

### Intro:

I am a newbie at R overall, but a veteran in trading.

I am trying to code simple signal in my R code, using quantstrat. But I got some error ( ref. below )

### The Code:

```
library( blotter )
library( quantstrat )

getSymbols( "UNVR.JK", from   = "2003-01-01",
                       to     = "2016-12-02",
                       src    = "yahoo",
                       adjust = T
                       )
unvr<-UNVR.JK
initdate<-"1999-01-01"

from<-"2003-01-01"
to<-"2016-12-02"

Sys.setenv( TZ="UTC" )
currency( "IDR" )

tradesize<-1000000
initeq<-1000000
strategy.st<-"firststrat"
portfolio.st<-strategy.st
account.st<-portfolio.st

initPortf(       portfolio.st,
                 symbols    = "unvr",
                 initDate   = initdate,
                 currency   = "IDR"
                 )
initAcct(        account.st,
                 portfolios = portfolio.st,
                 initDate   = initdate,
                 currency   = "IDR",
                 initEq     = 1000000
                 )
initOrders(      portfolio.st,
                 initDate   = initdate
                 )
strategy(        strategy.st,
                 store      = T
                 )

add.indicator(   strategy   =  strategy.st,
                 name       = "SMA", 
                 arguments  = list( x = quote( Cl( unvr ) ), n = 50 ), 
                 label      = "SMA50"
                 )
add.indicator(   strategy   = strategy.st,
                 name       = "RSI",
                 arguments  = list( price = quote( Cl( unvr ) ), n = 3 ),
                 label      = "RSI_3"
                 )
applyIndicators( strategy   = strategy.st,
                 mktdata    = OHLC( unvr )
                 )
add.rule(        strategy.st,
                 name       = "ruleSignal",
                 arguments  = list( sigcol   = "longentry", # use the longentry column as the sigcol
                                    sigval    = T,          # set sigval to TRUE
                                    orderqty  = 1,          # set orderqty to 1
                                    ordertype = "market",   # use a market type of order
                                    orderside = "long",     # take the long orderside
                                    replace   = F,          # do not replace other signals
                                    prefer    = "Open"      # buy at the next day's opening price
                                    ),
                 type       = "enter"                       # this is an enter type rule, not an exit
                 )


add.rule(        strategy   = strategy.st,                   # add a rule that uses an osFUN to size an entry position
                 name       = "ruleSignal",
                 arguments  = list( sigcol    = "longentry",
                                    sigval    = TRUE,
                                    ordertype = "market",
                                    orderside = "long",
                                    replace   = FALSE,
                                    prefer    = "Open",
                                    osFUN     = "osMaxDollar",   # use the osFUN called osMaxDollar
                                    tradeSize = "tradesize",     # the tradeSize argument should be equal to tradesize (defined earlier)
                                    maxSize   = tradesize        # the maxSize argument should be equal to tradesize as well
                                    ), 
                 type       = "enter"
                 )
chart.Posn(      Portfolio  = portfolio.st,
                 Symbol     = "unvr"
                 )
```

### The Error:

> `Error in chart.Posn(Portfolio = portfolio.st, Symbol = "unvr") :`
> `no transactions/positions to chart`

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory.  You do not have any trades available to chart positions, which is what `chart.Posn` is designed to do?

There are several things wrong:

- You're missing a call to `applyStrategy` to actually run a backtest (and generate trades).
- You also are missing relevant signal columns for `"longentry"`, which `add.rule` apparently wants to use, hasn't been define. You need to define `add.signal`(s) appropriately.
- You don't need to call `applyIndicators` if your goal is to run a backtest using `applyStrategy`.  `applyIndicators` simply runs what you define in `add.indicator`, and does not run signals or rules.

Comment: `applyStrategy(strategy=strategy.st, portfolios = portfolio.st)`
`updatePortf(portfolio.st)`
`daterange<-time(getPortfolio(portfolio.st)$summary[-1])`
`updateAcct(account.st, daterange)`
`updateEndEq(account.st)`
`chart.Posn(Portfolio = portfolio.st, Symbol = "unvr")` and it still gives me the same error, help me buddy

Comment: You're likely getting the same error because you still haven't done any trades in your `applyStrategy` call.  You don't provide enough information in your example for anyone to help, or reproduce it.  Look at the demo folder in quantstrat to see how a correct example runs.   By default, the trades done by the strategy will print to the R console.  Use `getTxns` after running your strategy to see what trades were done if you're unsure.